# Get models with distinct attribute ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a bunch of records in my database which all have the same Title but different Locations. Once I filter by within a location boundary, I want to filter out ones with the same Title. Is there an ActiveRecord way to do this? I know about `select`, but that will only return titles, and I actually need the entire record.

So I have a Business which has a Title. If I select all of the businesses within a given lat/long boundary, multiple instances with the same name (say, Subway) will be returned. I want to limit the result to 10.

In English: Given me ten records (the entire record, not just certain columns) where every title is unique amongst the ten returned.

Comment: Do you mean as in find_by_location?

Comment: Given several records with the same `title`, which one would you want to pick?

Comment: In this instance it doesn't matter. Any one of them (first might be easiest.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `.first`, i.e.

```
Venue.where(name: "Subway").first
```

If you need more than one element, pass a parameter to first:

```
Venue.where(name: "Subway").first(10)
```

To select one entry per distinct value in some column, you can use `.group("column_name")`:

```
Venue.where(some_condition).group("name")
```

Comment: How would you set this up with an :id? I have an index page of videos, and each one belongs to a director. I only want one video per director to be shown on the index page. Been trying for hours. Any help appreciated!

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland try ``.group(:director_id)`` (depending on how is your directors relation named.

Answer (score 0):

`ModelName.where(title: "Building")`

If you provide a more specific question, I'll provide a more specific answer...

Comment: Tried to be more specific. I have multiple records with the same title, but I only want one record per title name.